# How to return Partial from Razor Page when called from Xunit without getting System.NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0, xunit

Getting a `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` when attempting to return a Partial from a Razor Page handler that's being invoked from an Xunit test method.

Razor Page:

```cs
namespace SomeProject.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            return Page();
        }
        
        public async Task<PartialViewResult> OnGetTest()
        {
            return Partial("Modals/_Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Xunit class in a different project:

```cs
using SomeProject.Pages;
using Xunit;

namespace SomeProject.Pages.Tests.Xunit
{
    public class IndexUnitTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task OnGetTest_ReturnsPartial()
        {
            IndexModel pageModel = new IndexModel();

            IActionResult? result = await pageModel.OnGetTest();

            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.IsType<PartialViewResult>(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Partial located at `Views/Shared/Modals/_Test.cshtml`:

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

The Partial loads perfectly fine when running the RazorPage Project (i.e. `SomeProject.Pages`) and hitting the endpoint directly, the Razor Page server encounters no exceptions and serves the partial just fine to the user. Only when running it from Xunit does the aforementioned `System.NullReferenceException` appear.

[image: System.NullReferenceException when returning Partial]

How am I meant to test if a Razor Page Partial loads correctly without getting a NullReferenceException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need modify your unit test code like below:

```
[Fact]
public async Task OnGetTest_ReturnsPartial()
{
    var modelMetadataProvider = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(modelMetadataProvider, new ModelStateDictionary());
    var pageModel = new IndexModel
    {
        PageContext = new PageContext
        {
            ViewData = viewData
        },
        MetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider,
    };
        
    var result = await pageModel.OnGetTest();
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    Assert.IsType<PartialViewResult>(result);        
}
```

Reference:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Mvc/Mvc.RazorPages/test/PageModelTest.cs#L1922

Comment: Thank you so much! Once the culprit is known further information is much easier to find! [https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/24312](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/24312)